# Microsoft Graph Explorer - test with application permissions?

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

Is it possible to use Graph Explorer with application permissions i.e. authenticate with client_credentials as the grat_type?

I only know of the way to log in with an account which would be using delegated permissions.

If that is not possible can I at least use a bearer token that I created in Postman for example? I only see the option to get the token of the currently signed-in user to carry out further tests.

Comment: You're right that Graph Explorer is only for delegated permissions. For a client application, you can very easily obtain a token and run your requests using PowerShell, or another language